# Nuget Package Restore Error During CLI Publish Operation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore, asp.net-core-cli

I've been trying to script the Publish of a ASP.NET Core (on Core) application, but keep running into an annoying Nuget error (command in the following extract).

```
PS E:\PS> dotnet.exe publish E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.csproj /p:PublishProfil
e=Staging
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.csproj...
  Restore completed in 67.34 ms for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\AbatementReports\AbatementReports.csproj.
  Restoring packages for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.csproj...
  Restore completed in 53.43 ms for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.Data\CarpsAbatements.Data.csproj.
  Restore completed in 54.76 ms for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.Domain\CarpsAbatements.Domain.csproj.
  Restore completed in 71.16 ms for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\AbatementReports\AbatementReports.csproj.
  Restore completed in 946.64 ms for E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 17.2\DevExtreme\System\DevExtreme\Bin\AspNetCore' doesn't exist. [E:\Repos\Abatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements\CarpsAbatements.csproj]
```

As you can see from the attached screenshot, there is no Nuget Source which correlates to the error. And the DevExpress-Local sources are both unchecked anyway.

[image]

Is there any way I can be rid of this blocking error?
Have I got the publish command incorrect?

Cheers

Comment: Search for `nuget.config` in your project directory. Maybe there you will find custom configuration. Check your <User Profile>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config and see what is there. Run `dotnet publish` with `--verbosity diag` to see what's going on.

Comment: @Peska Thanks. There was indeed an entry in one of those config files. As they are not in the VS solution, I did not even realise they were there. I think I had only looked for a Packages file, not a Nuget.config. Fixed! Thanks!